# Pascal External:SIGSEGV

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I have a program that uses linked lists. It crashes with `External:SIGSEGV` when it gets to

`new(R);R:=queue;queue:=queue.Next;dispose(R);`

where I'm getting rid of the first element of the queue list, after dispose(R). What's even more weird - when I change it to `queue:=queue.Next` that is, just moving forward without dumping the element - it still crashes, after this command. It's worth mentioning that the value of `queue.Next=nil`. And when I tried just `queue:=nil;` it crashed too, leaving me absolutely puzzled. Can somebody help me? 

Edit: I've uploaded the whole code [here](http://pastebin.ca/2493835), relevant line is no. 128.

Comment: More code would be helpful; it's almost impossible to diagnose these kinds of problems without the context.

Comment: @EdCottrell ok, i've uploaded it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was dereferencing the pointer later and lazarus wasn't able to backtrack to that position so he pointed at the line where the pointer was set to nil.